# Google Cloud HTTP Load Balancer Slow Performance or 502 "failed_to_connect_to_backend"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Answering Own question:

A: Nginx and Apache time outs should be greater than 600 sec

B: If your HTTP google cloud load balancer has  multiple ports in the backend service like 80,443 . It causes this bug.

HTTP(S) load balancers proxy the connection to 80 so you dont need ,443 in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in description for "Slow performance or 502s "failed_to_connect_to_backend"

A: Nginx and Apache time outs should be greater than 600 sec

B: If your HTTP google cloud load balancer has multiple ports in the backend service like 80,443 . It causes this bug.

HTTP(S) load balancers proxy the connection to 80 so you dont need ,443 in the backend.

Comment: Thank you. B was the cause of my issue. Should be made clearer in the docs.